# Send data to a previous Fragment in the stack

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Activity that makes extensive use of Fragments.

The usual flow is:

Fragment **A** -> Fragment **B** -> Fragment **C** -> Fragment **D**

And sometimes I go back directly from **D** to **B** with

```
int id = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(1).getId();
getFragmentManager().popBackStack(id, 0);
```

It works fine. However, I don't have any reference in my Activity to Fragment **B**.

What's the best way to send Fragment **B** data that I just got in Fragment **D**?.

Comment: You can try setting up a broadcast receiver to trigger when Fragment B is visible: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: how did you resolve this.

Comment: @Tinker Both using a broadcast receiver and implementing callbacks worked for me. I like more the idea of using callbacks (a simple interface) though, but it'll only work if you have a way to access the current fragment from your Activity.

Comment: Thanks for repsonse @armandooj. I tried using interface callbacks,and it worked well with me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fragments are meant to be reusable, isolated UI components. They generally shouldn't have knowledge of each other. In keeping with the design principle of [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) you should have some sort of underlying data object that the fragments can operate on to save data.

Either the parent Activity can pass a reference to this data structure, or it can be a globally accessible object somehow (this question is abstract enough that providing a concrete response isn't feasible).