# how to pass data from one fragment to previous fragment?

Tags: android

I am going FragmentA->FragmentB. Now From FragmentB I want to pass data to FragmentA.So How can I do that??

Currently am going FragmentB->FragmentA with `getCustomFragmentManager().popBackStack();` 
but not passing any value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send data to a previous Fragment in the stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392733/send-data-to-a-previous-fragment-in-the-stack)

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32880451/6005977) It may be usefull.

Comment: Using interface or Broadcast receiver.

Comment: How would you like pass value ? I mean when FragmentB is destroyed or it is still visible

Comment: FragmentB is destroyed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass result from second fragment to first fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103953/how-to-pass-result-from-second-fragment-to-first-fragment)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

> In FragmentA

```
    FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    FragmentB frgamentB = new FrgamentB();
    fragmentB.setTargetFragment(FrgamentA.this, AppConstant.FRAGMENT_CODE);
    ft.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getName());
    ft.add(R.id.content, fragment, tag);
    ft.commit();
```

> Now Override `onActivityResult()` in FragmentA

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      if (requestCode==AppConstant.FRAGMENT_CODE){
         int addID = data.getIntExtra("addressID", 0);
         String addressLine=data.getStringExtra("addressLine");
      }
    }
}
```

> In FragmentB (on Click of back Button)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, FragmentB.class);
intent.putExtra("addressID", list.get(position).getId());
intent.putExtra("addressLine", list.get(position).getAddressLine1());
getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), RESULT_OK, intent);
getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

---

### Update In Kotlin

> FragmentExtention

```
fun Fragment.addFragment(fragment: Fragment,targetFragment: Fragment,requestCode: Int, isAddToBackStack: Boolean = false, init: Bundle.() -> Unit = {}) {
    requireFragmentManager().inTransaction {
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.init()
        fragment.arguments = bundle
        setTargetFragment(targetFragment,requestCode)
        if (isAddToBackStack) {
            addToBackStack(fragment::class.java.simpleName)
        }
        add(R.id.content, fragment, fragment::class.java.simpleName)
    }
}


inline fun FragmentManager.inTransaction(func: FragmentTransaction.() -> Unit) {
        val fragmentTransaction = beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction.func()
        fragmentTransaction.commit()
    }

fun Fragment.removeFragment(fragment: Fragment, enter: Int = 0, exit: Int = 0) {
    requireFragmentManager().inTransaction {
        remove(fragment)
    }
}
```

> In FragmentA

```
addFragment(FrgamentB(),this,AppConstant.FRAGMENT_CODE,true)
```

> Now Override onActivityResult() in FragmentA

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == FRAGMENT_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val addID = data?.getIntExtra("addressID", 0)
            val addressLine = data?.getStringExtra("addressLine")
        }
 }
```

> In FragmentB (on Click of back Button)

```
val intent = Intent(context, FragmentB::class.java)
intent.putExtra("addressID", list.get(position).getId()) 
intent.putExtra("addressLine",list.get(position).getAddressLine1())                
targetFragment.onActivityResult(targetRequestCode,RESULT_OK, intent)
fragmentManager.popBackStack()
```

Comment: Forgot to add ft.commit(); in FragmentA at the last line.

Comment: Where is "AppConstant" from?

Comment: @Jakob : It's just static code. You can use any code. I put that code in one AppConstant class.

Answer (score 6):

If using Kotlin, and android navigation architecture, you can use [like this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79672220#comment55), from Navigation 2.3.0-alpha02 release.

Set result on Fragment B:

```
findNavController().previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set("key", result)
```

Observe the result on Fragment A, with same key:

```
    findNavController().currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.getLiveData<Type>("key")?.observe(
    viewLifecycleOwner) {result ->
    // Do something with the result.
}
```

Comment: It is not working with onBackPressed() inside fragment B. How to use it?

Answer (score 5):

Since setTargetFragment has been [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#setTargetFragment(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment,%20int)). You can use [setFragmentResultListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager#setFragmentResultListener(java.lang.String,%20androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner,%20androidx.fragment.app.FragmentResultListener)).

In **FragmentA**

```
setFragmentResultListener("KEY") { reqKey, bundle ->
    if (reqKey == "KEY")
    {
        val result = bundle.getString("RESULT")
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Result: $result", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

In **FragmentB**

```
val resultBundle = Bundle().apply { putString("RESULT", "result from FragmentB") }
setFragmentResult("KEY", resultBundle)
```

Answer (score 1):

Work for me.

In FragmentB create interface callback like this

```
private FragmentCallBacks fragmentCallBacks;

public interface FragmentCallBacks{
    void onCallBack(String data);
}

public void setFragmentCallBacks(FragmentCallBacks fragmentCallBacks) {
    this.fragmentCallBacks = fragmentCallBacks;
}

//onDestroy add this code
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    fragmentCallBacks.onCallBack("This data from FragmentB");
}
```

And add this code in FragmentA

```
FragmentB fragment = new FragmentB();
replaceFragment(fragment, "TAG");
fragment.setFragmentCallBacks(data -> {
    //do something here with your data
});

public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(tag);
    fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score -1):

**FragmentA** call the **FragmentB** by using replace:

```
getFragmentManager!!.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, fragmentB, tag).addToBackStack(null).commit()
```

Then **FragmentB** press:

```
fragmentManager.popBackStack()
```

**FragmentA** In the **override fun onViewCreated()** try to listen:

```
fragmentManager!!.addOnBackStackChangedListener {
  if (fragmentManager!!.backStackEntryCount == 0) {
           // Here your code
  }
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question of passing data to the previous fragment?