# How to pass data from fragment adapter to previous fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-bundle

I have 2 fragments, let first fragment be A and second fragment be B. On the click of a button on fragment A, Fragment B is being opened which is having a recyclerview from this recycler view, I want to send data to fragment A whenever an item is being clicked in recyclerview.

For example: If I have a list of 3 items in recyclerview(Apple, Mango and banana) if the user selects mango, i want to display it on a textview in fragment A, as on item clicked Fragment B is popBack and fragment A is shown again.

Comment: Post your code what you have tried so far

Comment: @harmeet, Please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40110415/4748607)

Comment: add interface callback from fragment B to fragment A

Comment: @NiravBhavsar  thanku

Answer (score 0):

I'll just break down your question to simpler terms.

From a fragment **A**, you want to be able to send data to a fragment **B** just like the way Activities send data using Intents. However, you want this to be done only when there is a transition from fragment **A** to **B**.

Fragments are not allowed to communicate directly with each other. All Fragment-to-Fragment communication must be done through the parent Activity.

**NB:

If you're under a really tight schedule, just use [Event Bus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus). This library simplifies communication between activities, fragments, threads, etc. Otherwise, continue.**

Check out [this](http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-passing-data-between-fragments) link to learn how to pass data from one fragment to another. To ensure that data is sent only when the transition is between fragment **A** and **B**, just check if the Bundle being received is null.

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!